# Google Earth Engine - Name Layers with Image Image ID

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have recently started to explore google earth engine - and would like to know if there is a way to name image layers (within a collection) with the individual image ID? I have come this far:

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2019-03-01','2019-03-15')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
  .limit(5);


  var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};


function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection
  var id = image.id;
  var iMage = ee.Image(image.id);
  Map.addLayer(iMage, rgbVis, 'RGB');
}

s2.evaluate(function(s2) {  // use map on client-side
  s2.features.map(addImage);
});
```

Comment: Is this simply what you want? https://code.earthengine.google.com/b171307ba829ff9bd53b529947afcfaf

Comment: @Kuik - yes! exactly that - that was simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JB take in count that you are just adding the image by its ID, so if you make some process to the images in the collection, they will not be reflected in the images you add to the map